# Gitolite ssh commands

Tags: ssh, gitolite

I'm trying to get around with a running gitolite server. When running `ssh git@host info` I get the expected list of repositories. But when I try to run and other command e.g. `ssh git@host help` the server responds with **bad command: help**

Unfortunately the gitolite documentation didn't help with the troubleshooting :(

Any suggestions?
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected.

Based on how [gitolite uses ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/gl_ssh.html) (ie, using [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)), you will always get that error message for *any* command except:

- git commands (clone, push, pull, ...)
- gitolite commands explicitly [defined and enabled within gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html#gitolite-commands)

There is no interactive ssh session authorized with Gitolite.
Any command is intercepted and run through the gitolite script.
If it isn't one of the defined and enabled commands... you will get a "`bad command`" every time.

In this specific case, the configuration of gitolite the OP was using did not have `help` as a defined and enabled command; per follow-up comments.

Comment: Well but further commands e.g. "ssh git@host help" are listed within their documentation ... this doesn't really make sense as it seems that this would never work from scratch ...

Comment: @pagid it makes perfect sense: no interactive session, only a *very* limited set of command + git only commands.

Comment: I get your point technically - but once again, the documentation lists e.g. "ssh git@host help" or "ssh git@host D" just as normal commands - but setting up the server from scratch won't provide these commands. Anyways - thanks for the answer.

Comment: @pagid true, help should be available, strange. I will check on my gitolite server if I can reproduce the issue

Comment: nevermind - "help" is part of g3 (gitolite3) and that was the documentation we both were referring to - but I was "talking" to a g2 server which doesn't have the "help" command available by default and my BOFH didn't want to tell me that this could be the cause ;)