# Selective access to Git repository based on SSH

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, repository

I have a server with six Git repositories, to which I have read+write access through a single SSH account, all in /opt/git/, all owned by the SSH account.

I'd like to give somebody else read+write access the a few of the repositories, but not to all.

- How do I create a new SSH user that has access to only a few select repositories?
- Can I use filepermissions (currently 0755) to control this type of access?
- Are there any best practices?

It's unlikely we'll have a third developer for quite a while, atleast not before we get a proper sysadmin, so it's okay if it's "good enough for now".

Answer (score 0):

That would be best managed by **[gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256)** (an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html)), which would allow you to configure a list of:

- ssh user keys
- repositories

And associate the users you want to the right repos.

All users would still access those repos through ssh with the account git, but using their own public/private ssh keys (registered in gitolite config file), generated with a command similar to:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${H}/.ssh/myLogin" -C "My Gitolite access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```

Each user would set up a [`%HOME%/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906633/users-are-asked-for-password-while-using-gitolite/10909791#10909791) in order to reference `myLogin/myLogin.pub` keys.

Comment: Problem with gitolite is that it takes quite a while to setup and configure. I'd prefer something a little bit simpler.

Comment: @Martijn no it takes a few seconds only. I have one intallation automated (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh), but even manually it is only two commands, after having cloned the gitolite repo (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13646524/6309).

Comment: I guess I'll try it. Noticed you also had scripts for GitLab, which has a UI. What would you advise for somebody with limited sysadmin skills.

Comment: @Martijn Gitolite first, GitLab 5.1 second (it doesn't use Gitolite, but its own authorization layer)

Comment: OK, so `Gitolite` after all. Thanks @VonC for the links, I'll check it out and experiment 