# Auto deploy rails Gitlab projects to subdomains with Nginx and Phusion Passenger

Tags: git, nginx, passenger, gitlab

I've just installed Nginx, Phusion Passenger, and and Gitlab on a virtual machine. Almost all my projects will be rails applications. Instead of having to configure them individually, it would be great if I could automatically host them on a subdomain when a new project is created.

So when a user creates a project a nginx config file gets generated to respond to `[repo].[user].[mydomain].com`

My current plan is to have a script that somehow creates a copy of the master branch in a new location (say `/var/www/`) and then generate a matching nginx script.

How do I create a hook that can accomplish this? and how do I only create the repo once and just do a pull if it already exits?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) uses on [Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work).
And Gitolite allows for [update hook as VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358): you can declare one applied for all repos which would generate the file you want and make the appropriate actions, only if said repo is empty (just been created).