# Repository and User Access for git using gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

First I am new to GIT and gitolite. But I have read enough and cleared my basic concepts.
I was following Sitaram's tutorial https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite I wanted to ask few question for clarification and doubts.

1. I have a user git. Is it really necessary for a git user to have no password (user created with `--disabled-password` option (which I can't make it working on RHEL. but it worked on ubuntu))? I understand that git user must be accessible with ssh.
2. Lets say I have a GIT server and three clients gitadmin, cleintA and clientB. Now to make gitolite work, on gitadmin I copy clientA.pub, ClientB.pub (the public keys) to `keydir` then I edit my `conf/gitolite.conf` like as follows:

   ```
    repo phpsite
          RW+         =   clientA

    repo javasite
          RW+         = clientB
   ```

Now my question is when I commit these files and push them on server. What happens then?
How these repos are created? do I have to manually create them or gitolite will create it?

Now when clientA needs to clone/checkout the repo what url will it use?

`git@server.com:phpsite` or will it be `clientA@server:phpsite`.

I know this question may be a little stupid, but I really need to clear these doubts

Any help or hint is much appreciable.

---

**EDIT**

After VonC answer I implemented the gitolite and got around another Doubt.
Lets say I have a machine `clientA` which got two users `alice,bob` Now Ideally the public key should be `alice.pub and bob.pub` for these users. Now Question is can I generate and name a public key for `alice` like `alice-clientA.pub`? From my understanding a different file name should not be a issue for authentication. But what about  `conf/gitolite.conf` the users name under repo should be like

```
repo phpsite
   RW+     =  alice-clientA
```

OR

should it be same as before

```
 repo php:site
   RW+    =   alice
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it really necessary for a git user to have no password (user created with --disabled-password option)

No. '`git`'is a regular account.

> when I commit these files and push them on server. What happens then

Gitolite will create the bare repo `phpsite.git` and `javasite.git` in `~git/repositories/`, and it will modify `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` in order to call the gitolite script using `clientA` and `clientB` public keys and parameter.
It takes advantage of the ssh mechanism **[forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)**.

See more at "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256)".

You *always* use an ssh connection as user `git`:

```
git@server.com:phpsite
```

You never tries an ssh as `clientA`: ssh will authenticate you as `clientA` because of your `clientA` public/private ssh keys.

Comment: that was real quick !! :) thanks!. I treasure your mentorship. I thought for `git@server.com:phpsite` too. just wanted to confirm.
You saved the day

Comment: Hi! I just got another doubt. I have updated the question. would you please look into that ?

Comment: @SAM you don't need to generate a public key for each repo you want to access, alice.pub is enough. You would generate *another* public/private keys for alice only if alice were to access those same repos from *another* machine.

Comment: yeah thats correct!. But if you got two users on a same machine, Ideally the gitolite username in `conf` will be as the same name of public key file name. Are you trying to say for same machine I don't have to worry about creating so many public keys as much as users?

Comment: @SAM you have to make each user to create, on that same machine, a pair of public/private keys for each user and get from those users the public key renamed appropriately. Each pair of keys reside in `/home/auser/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` is is used by each user for their ssh connection. But those `id_rsa(.pub)` keys, adequately renamed after the user logins, are also copied in `gitolite-admin/keys` directory, and pushed back to the `gitolite-admin` repo.

Comment: alright. So My Public key name for alice on ClientA is `alice-clientA.pub` similarly for bob `bob-clientA.pub`. if I commit these files with same name. then in `gitolite.conf` I have to use same username as of the filename?

Comment: thanks. thank you so much.specially being so patient with me.

Comment: @SAM no problem. Sorry for the delay, I just woke up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26800/discussion-between-sam-and-vonc)