# Install gitolite v3 on the Centos 6.4. The second user is asking a password

Tags: installation, centos, gitolite

Please help me to understand what i am doing wrong. I have server on CentOS 6.4 and I need to install gitolite v3. What am i doing? by the first i am install one using next command:

```
yum install git* perl-Time-HiRes

useradd -m --system --shell /bin/bash --user-group gitolite

su - gitolite

mkdir bin


echo "PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH" > .bash_profile

source .bash_profile

ssh-keygen -t rsa

cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub ./gitolite.pub

git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

gitolite/install -ln

gitolite setup -pk gitolite.pub
```

Install was successful. Than I clone gitolite-admin repositories:

```
git clone gitadmin:gitolite-admin
cd gitolite-admin/keydir
```

And generate public key for the new user(lodar.pub)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f lodar
mv ./lodar ../../.ssh/lodar
```

Than i edit conf/gitolite.conf:

```
repo gitolite-admin
   RW+   = gitolite
repo testing
   RW+   = @all
repo   empty
   RW+   = lodar
```

Commit all changes:

```
git add keydir/lodar.pub
git commit -m 'add user lodar and new repo empty'
git push
```

And that is all. Push was successful too. After all manipulation i created .ssh/config

```
Host gitadmin
    User gitolite
    Hostname 192.168.0.1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

Host gitlodar
    User gitolite
    Hostname 192.168.0.1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/lodar
```

But if i try to connect using

```
ssh gitlodar info
lodar@192.168.0.1's password:
```

i must to enter the password.

```
ssh gitadmin info
hello, gitolite, this is gitolite@lodar-14452 running gitolite3 v3.5.1-4-g2f48a3e on git 1.7.1
R W   gitolite-amdin
R W   testing
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I understand you meant `cp` and not `mv`, but I can *assure* you the user should be `gitolite` in your `~/.ssh/config` file, as mentioned in my answer below. Always `gitolite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did:

```
mv ./lodar ../../.ssh/lodar
```

I supposed you meant

```
cp ./lodar.pub ../../.ssh/
mv ./lodar     ../../.ssh/
```

Because if you don't copy the public key in `~/.ssh`, you wouldn't be able to use it in an ssh session.

But the other mistake is in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitlodar
    User gitolite          # not loadar!
    Hostname 192.168.0.1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/lodar
```

See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256)":
The idea is to *always* use the *same* user to connect to the gitolite server (in your case, connect as '`gitolite`'), and open an *non-interactive shell.
The force-command ssh line will call the gitolite script with a parameter representing the name of the user (here '`loadar`'), because that named is registered with the public key in the `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pwd
/home/lodar/gitolite-admin/keydir    
$ssh-keygen -t rsa -f lodar
```

Last command generated two keys: public (lodar.pub) and private (lodar). I moved private key in the .ssh on my client computer. The public one stayed in keydir.

```
$mv ./lodar ../../.ssh/lodar
```

That is why after 'git push' user lodar added to giotlite repo. I checked it on the server by the command

```
$gitolite sshkeys-lint
sshkeys-lint: === checking authkeys file:
sshkeys-lint: === checking pubkeys:
sshkeys-lint: === gitolite.pub maps to user gitolite
sshkeys-lint: === lodar.pub maps to user lodar
```

YOU ARE RIGHT. MY MISTAKE was IN MY .ssh/config. Thanks for the HELP. it is working great now.

Comment: Right. +1. I have added the correct cp/mv commands in my answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will correct my first post and rename it to "How-to install gitolite" for other people.