# Gitolite, can't clone new repo

Tags: clone, gitolite, repository

I've just installed gitolite on my Debian server.
Then I cloned gitolite-admin repo and and new public key + following lines to conf file:

```
repo wallr_common
RW+ = wall
```

New repo was created after push.

At first I go to authorized_keys and saw that key for new user not exists, then I run `~/.gitolite/keydir$ gl-setup`, and the key appears in authorized_keys.

Now I'm trying to clone it but I'm getting error:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v  "ssh://wall@192.168.1.110:/wallr_common.git" "D:\wallr_common"

Cloning into 'D:\wallr_common'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (5834 ms @ 04.07.2013 0:27:46)
```

What can be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `git` or `gitolite` account for your ssh session. Not the user account `wall` that you registered in gitolite.

That means `ssh://git@...,` instead of `ssh://wall@...`.

Replace '`git`' with the account you used to install gitolite.

See more at "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

This is a similar mistake as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16911931/6309).

Comment: While using your version I'm getting:
R access for wallr_common DENIED to git

Comment: And what is the *full* output of: `ssh git@192.168.1.110` ? (again assuming here that you did installed gitolite and your bare repos in an account named '`git`': if it isn't the case, please tell me which account you used on the server side).

Comment: While trying to connect from local machine to server using git user and git.ppk (used for gitolite installation) I'm getting "server refused to allocate pty"

Comment: @ICE so that is the first step: that ssh command *must* work and return the hello message (see one example at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041898/6309). As long as this doesn't work, any clone won't work.

Comment: but I can clone gitolite-admin repo with git user, and I can push it back. The same putty output I'm getting while trying to connect with wall.ppk. But with git user I can work with repo and with wall - no.

Comment: Strange, I've just tried to clone repo with wall.ppk and ssh://git@... and it works. Thank you for help!