# How can I find who deleted a feature branch from our team project at GitHub?

Tags: git, github, branch, recover

We have a master branch and multiple feature branches. And found one feature branch is missing now. How can I find who deleted a feature branch from our team project at GitHub?

Comment: This is only something GitHub:Support can deal with

Answer (score 3):

We were able to figure this out by looking at the organization's newsfeed. To do this, go to https://github.com/dashboard, then click the account context switcher in the upper-left corner of the page. (also see https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-your-organizations-news-feed#accessing-your-organizations-news-feed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact GitHub support: only them have the logs able to identify who did that deletion push.

If you had control over the server, I explained in "[How to find out who delete a branch at git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010626/6309)" that you could look into the log of an intermediate layer that would do the audit trail for you (since Git, again, has no authentication and cannot do this kind of audit trail where you know who does what: no authentication means no "who").

But you don't have any control/access over the remote server GitHub. Hence the need to contact its support.