# GIT - account with access to one project

Tags: git, ssh

I have git master repository, I can visit it and create sub repo in my local computer. I'm using TortoiseGit in client machine but I would like to permit my client only to download one project from my git repository. So for example:

```
server projects:
 +test1
 +test2
 +test3
```

i would like to add permission for userX to download and work above test1 only.

Now, i'm accesing my server through the ssh so the ssh user should have permission to r/w only in test1 folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could add to your server an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html).
It interfaces well with ssh. See "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html)", and my own answer "[How Gitolite works?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

That way, you can configure precisely [who can access what](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/why.html) in a `gitolite.conf` file of a special repo `gitolite-admin`:

```
repo test1
    RW     =   user1
```