# Managing git - Master branch push permission

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to configure our git repo in a way that would only allow a pre defined set of users to push into master branch on origin ?

I have found certain tools that require payment for such a task, but was wondering whether this was supported in git by default, without the need for a git server tool.

Any comments and directions would be welcome.

Comment: you could use your linux or windows user permissions to the directory of you origin

Comment: gitlab is a free git server which is very nice. you can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22906383/2082964

Comment: possible duplicate of [git branch permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248246/git-branch-permissions)

Comment: Is it possible to set branch permissions using git bash? is not a duplicate of what I'm asking. An answer to my question would require guidance regarding how I can write a pre-recieve hook on server side to accept a set of hard coded users which I'm supposed to get by stdin.

Comment: There is probably a way; but will take you time, why reinvent the wheel if with gitlab you can have everything in a very fast way?

Comment: We already have a git server, changing it requires a battle with bureaucracy that is not feasible, and our discussion is starting to get off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to write a custom hook to listen each update and have a custom authentication solution.

Within the .git file there is a hook directory, which contains example implementations for custom hooks. Deleting the .sample suffix would simply make that hook become operational ( the hook examples there have callback registrations by default ).

Update hook would be triggered after each push, exiting 1 would simply disallow for that push to be applied. Something on the lines of :

```
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

author="$(git log $newrev -1)"

# user names on the white list
whitelist=( 'Admin1' 'Admin2' 'Admin3'  )

# branches to be controlled
master="refs/heads/master"
test="refs/heads/test"

if [[ "$refname" == "$master" || "$refname" == "$test" ]]
then
                for name in "${whitelist[@]}"
                do
                                echo $name
                                if [[ "$author" == *"$name"* ]] 
                                then
                                                exit 0
                                fi
                done
else
                exit 0
fi

echo "Master or test branch is not within your reach ! Contact your supervisor ! "
exit 1
```

I strongly advice you to write your own script according to your authentication policy. The above script is just to give an idea and is easily hackable.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not have any permission system of its own. You will have to use something else to manage them like [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com) or [gitolite](http://gitolite.com). You can also build your own using git hooks.

Comment: Thx for your reply, however I need more details regarding how I can write a pre-recieve hook. We do auth by basic http. I don't see how I am ever going to recieve stdin arguements from server side that carries the auth information.

Comment: That being said the tools you mentioned desire payment in our case, and I can not consider them as a feasible solution even if they didn't require payment, seeing as how there are other options.

Comment: You can install GitLab Community Edition and gitolite on your own servers without paying anything. If you really want to roll your own, start by [reading the docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Comment: Once again, we already have a git server. Changing it would require a lot of effort, not just on technical manner but at bureaucratic level. Therefore a simple hook script would be a much better solution in our case. Any directions towards there would be welcome.