# gitolite SSH Problems

Tags: git, gitolite, git-bash

I have Problems to connect to my gitolite server via GIT-Bash on Windows.
I have done the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

on my local windows machine an the git-bash. Afterwards I copied this keyfile to

```
gitolite-admin/keydir
```

on my the linux machine running the gitolite server

Then I added the new keyfile and commited/pushed the repository.

But everytime I try to do

```
git clone user@server-ip:testing.git
```

I get

```
fatal: 'testing.git' does not appear  to be a git repository
fatal: could not read  from remove repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

I had the same error message at the beginning when I tried to clone the gitolite-admin repo due invalid ssh-keys.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the name of the file you put in `gitolite-admin/keydir` folder? What version of gitolite are you using?

Comment: it is the username on the unix machine so, user.pub
the current version in the apt-get repository

Comment: Why are you using `user`? for `user@server-ip`? It usually is `git@server-ip`, or whatever account you used to install gitolite.

Comment: yes on the Server, but on the clients every employee will have its own account on the git server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gitolite, your ssh url *must* use the account used for installing gitolite (for example git), *even if* all users have an account on that server.

```
git clone git@server-ip:testing.git
```

It is the public key used for that ssh connection which will help gitolite authenticate the user requesting the clone.

See also for more "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

Comment: ah ok, but how can I set different rights to the repositories then?

Comment: @user2071938 through the gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html

Comment: but how does gitolite know which user is connecting? via the ssh keys?

Comment: @user2071938 exactly: that is why you must name the public key which you are putting in `gitolite-admin/keydir` after the user name. Again, this is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309.