# Authenticating Git Repository regardless the server authentication

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, svn, authentication

"Git" gurus, could you please help me in something

As far as I know, Git access could be manipulated through server user/group authentication. but is there is any way that I can use another access authentication regardless the OS server authentication?

I mean like SVN, Users only defined for SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh, combined with **[Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** (an access control library in Perl, for Git): that will use the matching between ssh public key, and the username defined only for Gitolite.

See more at "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

---

If you are using/installing Git hosting services like [GitLab (ruby)](https://about.gitlab.com/) or [GitbLit (java)](http://gitblit.com/), then  the users can be defined in a dedicated database for those services.

---

In both cases, the user authentication doesn't rely on the OS.

Comment: It seems very good solution, do I have to setup it on the clients machines. or just the server?

Comment: @MarwaDosoky only the server.

Comment: is it easy to integrate gitolite with egit of eclipse ? I don't want the developers to come scream every time they want to commit something, my main concern is how to clone a repository from eclipse with gitolite specific access configuration. while the wizard in eclipse only allows the usual ssh authentication

Comment: @MarwaDosoky gitolite is made for working with ssh access. As far as the developers are concerned, they simply clone a git repo using its ssh url as usual. As long as their public key has been added in the `gitolite-amin` repo (in the `keydir` folder) with the proper name, they won't see anything different.