# gitolite user asking for password

Tags: php, git, sourcetree

I use gitolite on a virtual ubuntu machine.

My repos are installed on user named "git".

From my virtual machine, I want to push to the repo, but I'm asked for user "git" password. I do not have a password for "git".

This doesn't help :

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /home/myuser/gitolite-admin/keydir/trogne.pub
```

How can I push to user "git" without having being asked for password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always pushing to a gitolite server (installed with default parameters) as user git.

But you need first to register you user key by:

- cloning gitolite-admin repo
- adding yor key in gitolite-admin/keydir/.pub
- pushing that new content back

That process will update the gitolite server `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and [call gitolite shell whenever you are pushing (as git) with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309) (and your public key).
If you are adding your key manually to the server, gitolite won't be called at the next ssh git push.

See "[add/remove users](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#users)" and "[how gitolite uses ssh](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html)":

[image: data:image/png;base64,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]