# Where does the "git" user come from in gitlab.com?

Tags: git, gitlab

When I create a new blank project in gitlab.com, I see `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:my-group1069/test-project.git` in the command line instructions page.

I'm curious about why is it not `git remote add origin mygitlabaccount@gitlab.com:my-group1069/test-project.git`.

[image]

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:my-group1069/test-project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin main
```

I think I should interact with gitlab with my gitlab account, not the `git` user.

Where does the `git` user come from?

Is it a built-in gitlab user?

Comment: There is a similar question on Github. I think Gitlab uses "git" as the ssh username for the same reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664768/why-does-git-using-ssh-use-git-as-a-username

Comment: @ElpieKay That actually looks like a straight duplicate to me - one of the answers mentions Gitlab, and the other is basically just using Github as an example.

Answer (score 3):

SSH is there to authenticate you through your registered SSH public key you registered to your GitLab account.

It is *not* there to open a remote shell with your "account": said account does not exist as a system user on the remote system. It (`mygitlabaccount`) only exists as an application account, an entry in the GitLab application.

Only the service (technical) account `git` does exist on the remote server.
And that one service account will refuse to open an interactive session. It will only allow to execute vetted commands (`git clone/push/pull/ls-remote/...`).