# How to set up a git server where users only have access to their repositories?

Tags: git

I'm building a service where users will send me their code via private git repos (similar to how users git push to Heroku). When a user signs up, I'd like to create repo that only they have access to via ssh key.

How would I set up a git server where users only have access to their individual repositories?

Creating SSH users for each user doesn't seem safe or scalable.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider still having each user public ssh keys, and identify them with said public key.

That is exactly what **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** is doing, and if your Git repository hosting service install Gitolite, you will be able to manage a separate access for each user and their repos.

See more in my answer to "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".