# gitolite FATAL: R any gitolite-admin git DENIED by fallthru

Tags: gitolite

> .ssh/config
>
> host git-server
>
> user git
>
> hostname 127.0.0.1
>
> identityfile ~/.ssh/git
>
> port 6827
>
> run: git ls-remote git-server:gitolite-admin.git

> error: FATAL: R any gitolite-admin git DENIED by fallthru (or you
> mis-spelled the reponame) fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Answer (score 0):

Simply try first [`ssh git@host info`](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#the-info-command)

> [That will]  tells you what version of `gitolite` and `git` are on the server, and **what repositories you have access to**.

That is better than ssh to the server, which a regular user could not do anyway, because their SSH public key is [associated to a gitolite "force command"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309): they cannot get an *interactive* session.

Note that for accessing the `gitolite-admin.git` main configuration repository, you need to use the key that you had when doing the [gitolite installation](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/quick_install)