# Failed to clone gitolite repo and lead to fatal error

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, gitolite

I am trying to clone the gitolite-admin.git repo **from my own server** after "successfully" installing gitolite (multiple ways: apt-package, github source), but it always gives the same error.

```
$ git clone git@******:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
git@******'s password:
fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

My setup

- on git user
- Ubuntu 20.04

---

I tried

- gitolite3 apt-package
- gitolite github version
- editing ~/.ssh/conf (from a previous stack overflow solution 8 years ago)
- access from same machine, but different user
- access from my main pc (different network)

---

I read/watched

- YouTube installations (from 2013)
- solutions from multiple different websites
- applying ssh sections from gitolite
- ...and nearly the whole docs from gitolite

---

What I discovered/think

- keydir for example doesnt even exist in my installation
- changing ~/.ssh/config didnt do anything
- most of previous solutions are simply outdated

I started working with gitolite only since today but already feel quite exhausted I am open for any solution offered, please help me if you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the Gitolite server: if you want to clone a gitolite-managed repository (including the main `gitolite-admin` one), your public key should be:

- listed in that `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file,
- preceded with the forced-command `command="[path]/gitolite-shell` (as I detail in "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)")

Otherwise, assuming your public key is registered (not for gitolite, just for regular interactive SSH session), then your clone would be:

```
git clone git@******:/full/path/to/gitolite-admin
```

The [OP justsomexanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8592812/justsomexanda) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042368/failed-to-clone-gitolite-repo-and-lead-to-fatal-error/63044400#comment111486222_63044400):

> I relinked my pub- and priv-keys.
> After rechecking them I could clone "`testing`" but not "`gitolite-admin`" so I looked closer and saw that in `repositories/gitolite-admins/gl-conf` there was the name of my key (which I called '`myKey`') but it was not the same identities which I logged in (named '`alex`').
> I changed the name in the conf and it worked.
>
> So in summary: **just check you name the keys right and you are using the correct identity**.

Comment: I mark this as the answer which solved it, tho it took a bit more. Your point checking the authorized_keys somehow made me recheck my ssh-keys and therefore I relinked my pub- and priv-keys. After rechecking them I could clone "testing" but not "gitolite-admin" so I looked closer and saw that  in repositories/gitolite-admins/gl-conf there was the name of my key (which I called 'myKey') but it was not the same identities which I logged in (named 'alex'). I changed the name in the conf and it worked. So in summary: just check you name the keys right and you are using the correct identity. Thanks

Comment: @justsomexanda Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.